# How to hide index?q= in php?

Tags: php, clean-urls

I am developing my application on core php and with that I am working on an application in which the index.php file loads all the template files according to the query. e.g; if user want to go to profile page, the url is, `sitename/index.php?q=profile`, and for settings page the url is, `sitename/index.php?q=settings`.

I want to make it clean url, like for profile the url should be like, `sitename/profile` and `sitename/settings`.

Comment: You should use .htaccess

Comment: see, I already know that I shoud use htaccess. The issue is I not good at htaccess and don't know what to code to achieve it.

Comment: Use Session or Cookies to store data of url...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use following code in your .htaccess file to have clean url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Thankyou vinit for you answer, But I have tried this code and this seems not be working in my xampp nor even in godaddy.

Comment: you have to enable "mod_rewrite" in your apache configuration.

Comment: Hey Vinit, thank you for the codes, I need to ask you something. This code works fine where there is something like, sitename/index.php?q=settings but if there is url like, sitename/index.php?q=settings/1234/xyz, it throughs 404 error, how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Either shift to MVC architecture and define your routes there accordingly, or use asynchronous requests through JavaScript and fetch and render stuff on the front end itself. Given your situation, both options would take about the same time to implement. Consider other factors of your project and then chose wisely.